# Quick Sort Implementation C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, quick-sort

Here is `qsort` implementation using iterators as it is in `std::sort`

```
// iterator check
template <typename It, typename T>
constexpr bool is = std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category, T>::value;


// quick sort
template <typename BidIt, typename Pred>
void qsort(BidIt first, BidIt last, Pred compare) noexcept
{
    static_assert(is<BidIt, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag> || is<BidIt, std::random_access_iterator_tag>,
        "bidirectional iterator required");

    auto size = std::distance(first, last);

    if (size > 1) {
        using content_type = std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::value_type;

        content_type pivot = *first;
        std::vector<content_type> left(size), right(size);
        auto left_end = left.begin();
        auto right_end = right.begin();

        for (BidIt i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
            compare(*i, pivot) ? *left_end++ = *i : *right_end++ = *i;
        }

        qsort(left.begin(), left_end, compare);
        qsort(right.begin(), right_end, compare);

        std::copy(left.begin(), left_end, first);
        *std::next(first, std::distance(left.begin(), left_end)) = pivot;
        std::copy(right.begin(), right_end, std::next(first, std::distance(left.begin(), left_end) + 1));
    }
}
```

Your thoughts?

Comment: Why the `noexcept`?  I don't think it gains you anything here. I recommend you [this article on noexcept](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/noexcept-what-for/).

Comment: @BenSteffan I heard it removes compiler generated code for handling exceptions and increases performance a bit, isn't it?

Comment: It might, or it might not. As I said, please read the article I linked you in my previous comment.

Comment: On `noexcept`: what if the copy constructor or assignment operator of `content_type` throws?  Your program will terminate.  It would be much more polite to allow that to propagate so the callers can decide what to do about it.

Comment: @aschepler clear, understood

Comment: @lisovskey, I recommend being careful when accepting answers, after 15 minutes you won't be able to change it.

Comment: @Incomputable Okay, let's see what else we can fix

Comment: I can't provide an example offhand, but it would be best to avoid recursion and make this iterative to avoid toppling the stack with extremely large inputs.

Comment: @Pharap We are trying to reach an elegant solution, for production we have the standard library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Incomputable](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/93301/incomputable) mentioned, [TemplateRex](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/23476/templaterex)'s ["How to Implement Classic Sorting Algorithms in Modern C++?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c/24650627#24650627) post on SO is a must-read.

---

```
// iterator check
template <typename It, typename T>
constexpr bool is = std::is_same<std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category, T>::value;
```

Don't pollute the global namespace for other users who might use your code.  Either wrap your helper trait types in their own namespace or alias the trait type locally.

Template arguments must be a type.  Don't forget `typename`.

---

```
        content_type pivot = *first;
```

Pivot selection is important for ensuring performance that avoids the worst case of \$O(n^2)\$.  Selecting the leftmost (as you did) or rightmost for a pivot makes quicksort vulnerable to sequences that are either ordered or reverse-ordered.

---

```
        std::vector<content_type> left(size), right(size);
```

If you refer to [`std::vector`'s constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) documentation, you will notice neither `explicit vector( size_type count );` nor the allocator accepting version are `noexcept` as either could throw.  That violates the commitment you made in your function signature that `qsort` was `noexcept`.

You are constructing the container with `size` default-inserted instances of `content_type`. What happens if `content_type` is not [`DefaultInsertable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/DefaultInsertable)?

---

```
        for (BidIt i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
            compare(*i, pivot) ? *left_end++ = *i : *right_end++ = *i;
        }
```

By only partitioning the elements that match your comparator, your partitioning algorithm is likely to exhibit worse-case performance as more elements are repeated in a sequence.

Know your [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm)'s.  See [`std::partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy).

---

```
void qsort(BidIt first, BidIt last, Pred compare) noexcept
```

After examining your entire implementation of `qsort`, why not allow [forward iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) support?

---

Optimizations:

Use a better pivot selection.  If you select the ends, you are vulnerable in the worst case on sorted and reversed sorted inputs.  If you select the middle element, you are vulnerable to bell-curved inputs.  Better Single-Pivot options would include median-of-3 and [ninther](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Ninther).  There is also a [Dual-Pivot approach](http://codeblab.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf) to quicksort.

For single-pivot partitions, you should guard against sequences with many repeated elements by using [three-way partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem).

Partition in-place.  Your partition algorithm wastes a lot of space as it allocates two temporary buffers that cover the full sub-sequence.

You can optimize pivot selection and partitioning to the iterator type.  See [Alexander Stepanov's Notes on Programming](http://stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf).

Consider using insertion sort at a certain threshold.  Insertion sort performs fewer operations (swaps, comparisons, etc) and takes advantage of architecture caching for smaller arrays.

Reduce more space by taking advantage of tail-call optimization.  Call qsort into the smaller side first then use a tail-call to recurse into the larger half.

Answer (score 10):

**Advice 1**

You can save some indentation space:

```
if (size > 1) {
    ... // Lots of code.
}
```

to

```
if (size < 2) {
    return;
}
... // Lots of code here.
```

**Advice 2**

You can do the partitioning in-place; there is no need for asking for more memory. The pseudocode in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) is rather detailed, uses no auxiliary memory (except for the recursion stack, of course) and is easy to follow.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60348/discussion-on-answer-by-coderodde-quick-sort-implementation-c11).

Answer (score 5):

1. You forgot specifying your includes, so they won't be scrutinized. FWIW, you need `<iterator>`, `<type_traits>` and `<vector>`. My changes trade `<vector>` for `<algorithm>`.
2. Check for the base-class instead of an exhaustive list of base and all derived types.
3. Insert `typename` to mark dependent types as types.
4. Provide defaults for template- and function-arguments where ou can for maximum convenience and versatility.
5. Use early-return to completely handle what you can immediately. Remember that the most important resource is the readers limited concentration.
6. Don't limit yourself to copyable types. An additional benefit from not copying the pivot is smaller stack-frames.
7. Avoid allocating additional space, it's expensive. That also allows you to minimize copying.
   See [Fastest algorithm of dividing array into positive and negative numbers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/348820/fastest-algorithm-of-dividing-array-into-positive-and-negative-numbers) for an efficient in-place way to divide a range.
8. Are you sure you want to abort your program if sorting fails for any reason? Or was marking the function `noexcept` just a bit too much?
9. Getting the size of the range is potentially an O(n) operation. Avoid that.
10. The algorithm degenerates to O(n) if all elements are equal.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>
#include <algorithm>

// quick sort
template <typename BidIt, typename Pred
    = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::value_type>>
void qsort(BidIt first, BidIt last, Pred compare = {})
noexcept(noexcept(compare(*first, *first), std::iter_swap(first, first)))
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag,
        typename std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::iterator_category>(),
        "at least bidirectional iterator required");

    if (first == last || first == last - 1)
        return;

    const auto& pivot = *first;
    auto left = first; ++left;
    auto right = last;

    do {
        do --right;
        while (left != right && !compare(*right, pivot));
        while (left != right && compare(*left, pivot))
            ++left;
        if (left != right) {
            std::iter_swap(left, right);
            ++left;
        }
    } while (left != right);

    std::iter_swap(first, left - 1);

    qsort(first, left - 1, compare);
    qsort(left, last, compare);
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the code you proposed? `static_assert` doesn't work for some reason (even with `std::`), binary `<` should be `!=`. As I said I prefer the lack of `return` or `break` if it possible. And as for `noexcept`, I don't understand what is going on there, are you swapping `first` with `first`?

Comment: I figured out what had been wrong with assert

Comment: My modified `noexcept`-construct checks whether the basic operations used are `noexcept`. But `noexcept` is an unevaluated context.

Answer (score 4):

**General note:** `std::sort()` implementation varies from libc++ to libstdc++, but in general they are far more complicated. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c) might be interesting for you.

**Thoughts:**

- This will not work on non default constructible types (because of `left` and `right` construction).
- It would be nice to default `Pred` to `std::less<>` (or typed one for C++11) and make `compare` be defaulted to default construction

  ```
  template <..., typename Pred = std::less<>>
  ... ...(..., Pred compare = {}) 
  {
   ...
  }
  ```
- The code needs `typename` before `std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::iterator_category`, since `iterator_category` is a dependent type.
- The error wording should say "at least" to be concise.

Full code with [demo](https://ideone.com/anlLdB):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

// iterator check
template <typename It, typename T>
constexpr bool is = std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category, T>::value;


// quick sort
template <typename BidIt, typename Pred = typename std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::value_type>>
void qsort(BidIt first, BidIt last, Pred compare = {}) noexcept
{
    static_assert(is<BidIt, std::bidirectional_iterator_tag> || is<BidIt, std::random_access_iterator_tag>,
        "at least bidirectional iterator required");

    auto size = std::distance(first, last);

    if (size > 1) {
        using content_type = typename std::iterator_traits<BidIt>::value_type;

        content_type pivot = *first;
        std::vector<content_type> left, right;
        left.reserve(size);
        right.reserve(size);
        auto left_end = std::back_inserter(left);
        auto right_end = std::back_inserter(right);

        for (BidIt i = std::next(first); i != last; ++i) {
            compare(*i, pivot) ? *left_end++ = *i : *right_end++ = *i;
        }

        qsort(left.begin(), left.end(), compare);
        qsort(right.begin(), right.end(), compare);

        std::copy(left.begin(), left.end(), first);
        *std::next(first, std::distance(left.begin(), left.end())) = pivot;
        std::copy(right.begin(), right.end(), std::next(first, std::distance(left.begin(), left.end()) + 1));
    }
}

struct integer
{
    integer() = delete; //not default constructible
    integer(int y):
                x(y)
    {}

    int x;
};

bool operator<(const integer& lhs, const integer& rhs)
{
    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const integer& x)
{
    os << x.x;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<integer> v{1, 0, -1, 4, 2};
    qsort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<integer>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what left and right construction do you mean? Thanks for the default predicate, it so handy

Comment: @lisovskey, the code uses constructor that will default construct size copies of element type.

Comment: I use only vector constructor, it should always work I suppose

Comment: @lisovskey, when constructing `left` and `right` you use 3rd constructor mentioned on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). I'll write an example tomorrow. Please ping me if I forget. Understanding this is important.

Comment: Okay, so what that constructor can spoil? Can you propose a way better?

Comment: @lisovskey, reserve then push back. There are possibilities to conditionally use one version on def constructible types, and another on non def constructible types.

Comment: @lisovskey, [here is what it can spoil](https://ideone.com/KaJh1e). I've fixed the `typename` thing.

Comment: @lisovskey, I've updated the post with full code.